How can both angular displacement and angular distance share similar equations?
Equation for finding angular displacement is:
$$ d\vec{\theta} = \vec{\omega} dt$$
In the case of rotational motion with constant acceleration, we can use the following equation for angular velocity:
$$\vec{\omega} = \vec{\alpha} t$$
By integrating both sides of the first equation, we get:
$$\int_{\vec{\theta_1}}^{\vec{\theta_2}} \vec{\theta} dt = \int_0^t \vec{\alpha} t dt$$
Thus we obtain the equation:
$$\Delta \vec{\theta} = \dfrac{1}{2} \vec{\alpha} t^2$$
Magnitude of this vector is thus:
$$\Delta \theta = \dfrac{1}{2} \alpha t^2$$
My question is: if we plug certain $t$ at which body may have completed several revolutions, we will obtain angular displacement bigger than 2 $\pi$ which does not make any physical sense. It also turns out that $\theta = \Delta \theta$ What did I miss?

There exist physical systems wherein even a $2\pi$ rotation doesn't cause the system to return to its original orientation though. A helical path can show that the radius vector can rotate around a central axis by $2\pi$ and yet never return to its original point.

Yes, they do exist. However, for the sake of simplicity let’s assume that an object is just an ordinary spinning disc. How would you explain the problem of angular displacement bigger than $2 \pi$ radians

An angular displacement of greater than $2 \pi$ simply denotes multiple rotations. The final state of the system may not be distinguishable from some other cases where it has turned the same angle $\pm$ a multiple of $2 \pi$ but the body still did turn that much.
As for why the values of $\theta$ and $\Delta \theta$ are the same: it is simply because you chose to start at $\theta = 0$, and so the total change in angle is equal to your final angle.

If I got everything right, angular displacement cannot be larger than 2 $\pi$ radians since it would make no sense to say that angle between initial and final radius vector is $7 \pi$ radians

It seems alright to me to say that the radius vector turned $7 \pi$ radians. If this does not sit well with you, you could define the displacement mod $2\pi$, i.e only take the part that remains after a whole number of rotations.

Isn’t the angular distance supposed to be the total angle radius vector has turned? There would be no distinction and not very much purpose of angular distance if we defined it that way. As for the remainder it does seem to me like a nice solution, but mathematically looks very sloppy

@AlexanderDjurovich Turn 2 radians counterclockwise. Angular distance and angular displacement from zero are both 2. Now turn 1 radian clockwise. Angular distance is 3 but angular displacement is 1, since only in the latter is the sign included. In your setup, you are only making one turn in the positive direction which is why the two are identical.

Also, @AlexanderDjurovich, I do not see either why it should be an issue that you can move through several revolutions. The remainder-approach that CompassBearer mentions was just a way to remove all extra full revolutions, and there is nothing "mathematically sloppy" about that - in fact, this value is known as the principal angle or the principal argument and is often the part that you would be interested in.

Angular displacement is a vector only under the condition of small angular displacement, in that case, the angular velocity can be defined by $\vec \omega =\frac {d \vec \theta}{dt}$. However, bigger displacements are not vectors. Consider this situation that, you have two rotation: A, rotate 90d with axis X; B, rotate 90d with axis Y. You will find out the combination rotation C with two steps (A then B) is different with the combination rotation C' (B then A). In other word ,$$C=A+B;C'=B+A;but,C\neq C'$$In engineering practice, we use tensor to express rotaion:$$
A^1=\begin{pmatrix}
cos x_1 & -sin x_1 & 0 \\
sinx_1 & cosx_1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$$$
A^2=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & cosx_2 & -sinx_2 \\
0 & sinx_2 & cosx_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$$$
A^3=\begin{pmatrix}
cos x_3 & 0 & -sinx_3 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
sinx_3 & 0 & cosx_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A^1$ is the rotation with axis Z,$A^2$ is the rotation with axis X and $A^3$ is the rotation with axis Y. Use them, C can be expressed by $C=A^2 A^3$ and so on C' :$C=A^3 A^2$. Now back to your question, the rotation notations can handle periodicity efficiently.
